# How to Pull Transaction Information Using lucid-cardano Library in TypeScript?

Tags: lucid, offchain

I'm working on a Cardano project using TypeScript, and I'm trying to fetch transaction details using the `lucid-cardano` library. Specifically, I have a transaction hash and I'm interested in retrieving all related information, such as the spent UTXOs.

Here is some pseudo-code to illustrate what I'm trying to achieve:

```typescript
import { SomeModule } from 'lucid-cardano';

const txHash = "some_transaction_hash_here";

async function getTransactionInfo(txHash: string) {
  // Code to pull transaction info using lucid-cardano
}

getTransactionInfo(txHash)
  .then(info => {
    console.log('Transaction Info:', info);
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error('An error occurred:', err);
  });
```

I'm facing difficulties in figuring out the appropriate API calls or methods provided by `lucid-cardano` to achieve this. The library documentation is not very detailed in this. If `lucid-cardano` is not suitable for this task, are there any alternative libraries that could serve the purpose?
I'm using Blockfrost as provider.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!